# On sort, table body is empty

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

When I click sort on any row, table body is empty. I load data from firebase then append it on table body once I was able to retrieve data.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="card" style="padding: 10px; margin: 50px;">
    <table id="myTable" class="display table-responsive-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Last activity</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript code, this just initializes data tables and retrieve data from firebase throug the loadUsers function

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );

window.onload = function(){
    admin.load();
}

var admin = {

    database: null,

    load: function(){
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        this.database = firebase.database();
        this.loadUsers();
    },

    loadUsers:function(){
        let usersRef = this.database.ref('users');
        usersRef.orderByChild("info/lastMessage").on("value", (snapshot) => {
            $('#tableBody').empty();
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                $('#tableBody').append('\
                <tr>\
                    <td>'+moment(child.val().info.lastMessage).format('D MMM h:mm:ss A')+'</td>\
                    <td>'+child.val().info.email+'</td>\
                    <td align="center"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Block</button></td>\
                    <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete Messages</button></td>\
                </tr>\
                ')
            });
        });
    },
}
```

[image: here is the loaded html]

[image: when i click sor, here it is]

Comment: It seems your table sets empty successful, but when you append it that does not work. Are you sure the variable `snapshot` is not empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the DataTables plugin in `ready` event which occurs **before** `load` event where you add table data.

Instead you need to initialize DataTables plugin **after** adding the data.

For example (not tested):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    admin.load();
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

I am not familiar with Firebase but if it returns a Promise when data is available, then you need to initialize the DataTables plugin as a response to event when that happens.

Alternatively you can initialize DataTables plugin **before** getting the data and use [`row().add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) API method to add data to the table. That maybe preferred as it looks much cleaner that generating HTML markup.